# How can I close all Windows photo viewer windows in Microsoft Windows 7 at once?

Tags: windows-7, windows-photo-viewer

I wonder how I can close all [Windows photo viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Photo_Viewer) windows in Microsoft Windows 7 at once.

I typically use `taskkill`, e.g. `taskkill /f /im mspaint.exe` or `taskkill /f /im putty.exe`, however my understanding is that Windows photo viewer is part of the `explorer.exe` process, which I don't want to terminate.

Comment: This is the location of the file,  "C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", so have you tried taskkill /f /im PhotoViewer.dll ?

Comment: If you watch task manager when opening an image for the first time it uses C:\Windows\System32\dllhost.exe to open Windows Photo viewer.

Comment: PhotoViewer.dll  is not a task, so that won't work.

Comment: @Tealkine Thanks, I have just tried: `taskkill /f /im PhotoViewer.dll`. I think Moab is right.

Comment: @Moab Thanks, `taskkill /f /im dllhost.exe` does the trick. Maybe it has some side effects sometimes, but so far so good.

Comment: @Moab Please right an official answer for future viewers

Comment: Can you program?  You can programmatically send a WM_CLOSE event with the postmessage function which you can do in C or even visual basic.  You could write a program to cycle through all open windows and send WM_CLOSE to windows identified as windows photo viewer.

Comment: @Tealkine thanks, that's true, but often have a bunch of explorer windows open that I would rather avoid to close :-)

Comment: @cybernard Yes, as a last resort I could code it. Just wanted to make sure that I don't reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed in task manager when I opened a photo that dllhost.exe popped up, so I killed it in task manager and Windows Photo Viewer closed.

try

> taskkill /f /im dllhost.exe

Answer (score 4):

You can close all the windows from the Windows task bar.  Just right click on the Photo Viewer icons and select "Close All Windows":

[image: task bar close all windows]

Comment: Thanks, interesting, I cannot use it as I don't combine windows but it's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

taskkill /f /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Photos*" /t